# pngcrush: uncrush on linux?

Tags: ios, sdk, png, pngcrush

Apple's iOS SDK use a modified version of pngcrush for converting png files in iOS bundles. 
Their version can also revert the changes (using the "-revert-iphone-optimizations" switch), but the original version can't.

Is there a tool that can be run on Linux and revert the iphone optimizations?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[iphone-fixpng](http://www.cyberhq.nl/files/iphone-fixpng.tgz) works in Linux. See this [discussion](http://web.archive.org/web/20090625062109/http://www.modmyi.com/wiki/index.php/Iphone_PNG_images) explaining what it does. I'm linking to web.archive.org because the original is down.

Comment: Please read the question. pngcruch binary that is provided with iOS sdk includes Apple's code that is not available in original version of pngcrush. It should be on http://www.apple.com/opensource, but  sadly it's not.

Comment: Guilty as charged. I rewrote my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, the discussion you linked to had a link to something even better (for my needs) - a Python based "iPhone PNG Images Normalizer" - http://axelbrz.com.ar/?mod=iphone-png-images-normalizer.

Comment: Hi does anyone have an updated link where to find the iphone-fixpng app?

Answer (score 3):

You can choose to use one of this:

1. Install Hackintosh inside linux, with VirtualBox. install Xcode inside it, then do something like [this](http://blog.egopoly.com/2011/05/03/how-to-uncrush-pngcrushed-images-from-an-iphone-app-bundle/)

   ```
   $ /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -dir uncrushed -revert-iphone-optimizations -q *.png
   ```

   This uses a modified pngcrush from apple to undo its optimizations. Guess this will work with all crushed pngs. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338019/where-is-pngcrush-for-xcode-4-3) for more accurated command **xcrun**
2. Download [iPIN.py](http://www.axelbrz.com.ar/ipin1.0.zip) from [this blog](http://www.axelbrz.com.ar/?mod=iphone-png-images-normalizer) and execute as

   ```
   $ python ipin.py
   ```

   This will uncrush all files from actual directory and its subdirectories. Don't worry about call it twice, from my experience does not corrupt already uncrushed pngs. From [here](http://www.jongware.com/pngdefry.html) you will find that ipin.py does not deoptimize all apple pngs

   > It (***ipin.py***) cannot handle multiple IDAT chunks, does not work with Adam7 interlaced images, and does not fix pre-multiplied alpha.
3. Use an specific [gnome binary tool](https://github.com/hadess/fixpng-thumbnailer). This needs a few low level steps:

   ```
   $ git clone https://github.com/hadess/fixpng-thumbnailer.git
   $ cd fixpng-thumbnailer
   $ ./autogen.sh
   $ make
   $ sudo make install
   ```

   After that, you have available a new command *gnome-fixpng-thumbnailer* which works like this

   $ gnome-fixpng-thumbnailer [INPUT FILE] [OUTPUT FILE]

   Take care with this command, because it corrupts pngs if is called twice on same png.

   I use it this way:

   ```
   $ for file in *.png; do echo "   $file";gnome-fixpng-thumbnailer $file $file; done
   ```

   You will guess why echoed the filename. Thats because this command could fail silently, (no $? with nonzero if fails) and the only clue you will have is a "ZLib error! -3" message. It's a quick solution because funnily enough you will find *ipin.py* does uncrush those files.

Read [this](http://www.jongware.com/pngdefry.html) for yet another tool around **pngdefry**. It provides an invaluable info about all this stuff -even its source- but I haven't tried myself.

My hope is in [pngcrush](http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/) absorbs those functionality so you have it out of the box, at least I have send a mail to pngcrush maintainer (hi Glenn).

Comment: I have no plans at the moment to absorb pngdefry capability into the real pngcrush, but I have put a link to pngdefry on the pngcrush page at SourceForge.